# pow function in C not working as intended

Tags: c, pow

I have the following equation I need to represent in C:

```
20 * 2^((1-x)/5)
```

my c representation is as follows, but it seems like the `pow` function is always returning a high integer value (1073741824) with my n values ranging from 1-5.

```
double x = 20 * pow(2.0, (n/5.0));
```

I assume it is because both arguments are not double values, but I do not see why. Is there a different way to format this equation to get it to work?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What is `n` ? Suggest `((1.0 - n)/5.0)`.

Comment: When setting `n=2` I get `x=17.411011` which seems correct to me - what did you expect and what did you get?

Comment: I edited the question, I have included math.h.

Answer (score 3):

I just compiled the example you give and it works

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main () {
    for (int n = 1; n <= 5; ++n) {
        double x = 20 * pow(2.0, ((1-n)/5.0));
        printf("%lf ", x);
    }
}
```

Output

```
20.000000 17.411011 15.157166 13.195079 11.486984
```

Make sure you use `int n` and not `unsigned n`. In case of `unsigned` you will get `(1 - n)` overflow and `pow` will return `inf`.

Comment: problem must be somewhere else in the program, thank you for taking the time. I will ask another question if I can't figure it out for myself.

Answer (score 2):

Your compiler is assuming `pow()` returns an int,

Remeber to `#include <math.h>` for the proper prototype

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// ipow works as pow when the compiler assumes an int return value
int ipow(double base, double exp) {
    double res = pow(base, exp);
    return *(int*)((void*)&res);
}

int main(void) {
    for (int n = 1; n < 6; n++) {
        double x = 20 * pow(2.0, ((1-n)/5.0));  // with correct prototype
        double y = 20 * ipow(2.0, ((1-n)/5.0)); // when compiler assumes int
        printf("n=%d, x=%f, y=%f\n", n, x, y);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See https://ideone.com/XvPWX6

Output:

```
n=1, x=20.000000, y=0.000000
n=2, x=17.411011, y=422418048.000000
n=3, x=15.157166, y=1240833840.000000
n=4, x=13.195079, y=-1971682192.000000
n=5, x=11.486984, y=-2036727536.000000
```